# What is the website address that automatically shows related content instead of pointing to the paper or books

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I was looking for vector bundles online, and I found a website that shows all the related results. By related results, I mean theorems/propositions/definitions, etc. It is not [ProjectEuclid](https://projecteuclid.org/), which only shows the corresponding paper and books. Unfortunately, I have lost the website.

This website can change the way mathematical research works. Finding the results is some of the most time-consuming tasks for mathematicians. For example, if I find all the definitions for vector bundles, I would have to read many books since there are different ways of generalizing them, then I would have to look for new papers to see whether there is something new. Or you can ask here and wait for days until there is an answer.

I am unsure whether this is the right place to ask this question since I am primarily interested in at least graduate-level questions, so Quora or Reddit have people that are mainly under that level. On the other hand, this place is at the right level, but I have primarily seen specific questions. If this were to be deleted, would anyone be so kind as to tell me which website I should ask this question to? Thank you so much.

Comment: The meta aspect of this should go on [meta] but I don't see anything in the site rules to prohibit asking about a specific, well-defined resource. Perhaps it would be useful if you could add more details about what exactly you are looking for (features, layout, site name?) just to narrow it down further.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to find it later.

Comment: The web site is called google.com

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of nLab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vector+bundle

Comment: It also sounds a bit like the [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01M1).